# Why does GetSection("test").GetChildren() returns sorted list of descendent sub-sections?

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-6.0

We are using these subsections to generate excel, and we want the list of sub-sections as it is stored in json file but GetSection("XPaths").GetChildren() is always returning sorted list of sub sections.

I am not able to understand why?
Here I want these Xpaths as it is stored in json file but I am always getting sorted data.

JSON: Here I shared only 4 values of XPath, in real it has more than 1000.

```
{
  "XPaths": {
    "CITY": "USER/@CITY",
    "STATE": "USER/@STATE",
    "COUNTRY": "USER/@COUNTRY",
    "GENDER": "USER/@GENDER"
            }
}
```

Code:

```
 public static Dictionary<string, string?> GetXpaths(string form)
        {
            var xPaths = new Dictionary<string, string?>();
            try
            {
                form = !File.Exists($"{form}.json") ? ($"{(int)FormToGetXpaths.Default}") : form;
               
                var xPathbuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile($"{form}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                var _xpathconfiguration = xPathbuilder.Build();

                 xPaths = _xpathconfiguration.GetSection("XPaths")
                    .GetChildren()
                    .ToList()
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Console.WriteLine($"Failed to get XPaths for {form}\n{ex.Message}");
            }
            return xPaths;
        }
```

Comment: Even if GetChildren returned the elements in their original order, this order would be lost by the `ToDictionary` call in your code.

Comment: @Dreamer You have to post your json too, if you really need some help, not just explanations.

Comment: @Serge Updated question and shared json there. My bad I forgot to post it initially.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) explicitly states that

> An object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array.

So you can't rely on the order being preserved. Some JSON serialization libraries might preserve it, some not, some others might have settings to control the sorting behavior, but in general, if you want your sections ordered in a specific way, you'll have to add a sequence variable to each of them and then order them by that variable.

Alternatively, you may consider turning your object with keys into an array of objects - the order in arrays *is* preserved according to the standard.

Comment: we have 100 of json files and every json file has 1000s of xpaths stored so adding sequence no. doesn't look feasible here :(

Comment: @Dreamer Well, then you might have to implement the (part of) deserializer yourself. I've done a quick lookup of the serialization libraries for different languages and I was unable to find any C# ones that actually preserve the order of object keys (in e.g. Perl there are some). You might get some inspiration from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925965/order-of-properties-get-messed-up-when-serialized-by-json-net. In short, you will want to deserialize your objects into arrays of KeyValuePair which then can be ordered as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try this instead of building config

```
public static Dictionary<string, string?> GetXpaths(string form)
{
    try
    {
        form = !File.Exists($"{form}.json") ? ($"{(int)FormToGetXpaths.Default}") : form;
    
        var basePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var json = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(basePath, $"{form}.json"));

        return JObject.Parse(json)["XPaths"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to get XPaths for {form}\n{ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
}
```